# Very minor grammar error in users page for tags: "non community-wiki" should have a dash to be "non-community-wiki"

Tags: bug, tags, grammar

At https://stackoverflow.com/tags/numerical-methods/topusers (and indeed, the same page for any tag), there is a very minor grammar error at the very bottom of the page:

> Only non community-wiki questions and answers are included in these totals (updated daily)

There should be a dash between "non" and "community-wiki", e.g:

> Only non**-**community-wiki questions and answers are included in these totals (updated daily)

Answer (score 5):

You are correct.

Unless I'm mistaken, the sentence should also have an [ending period](https://stackoverflow.design/content/guidelines/grammar-and-mechanics/#periods), like so:

> Only non-community-wiki questions and answers are included in these totals (updated daily).

---

The lack of a [hyphen](https://stackoverflow.design/content/guidelines/grammar-and-mechanics/#hyphens) in *"non community-wiki"*, and the lack of a period at the end of the sentence, also happens at the bottom of the [*hot*](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/numerical-methods/hot) tab with the following sentence:

> Only top voted, non community-wiki answers of a minimum length are eligible

Coincidentally, both tabs use a different font size for the end sentence.

---

Lastly, the following sentence at the bottom of the [*new*](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/numerical-methods/new) tab could also possibly use a period:

> Top 50 recent answers are included